How to set Default Action on alb Listener when use AWS::CodeDeploy::BlueGreen hook
I follow the example on
blue-green-template-example.
But when I change DefaultActions
from
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          ForwardConfig:
            TargetGroups:
              - TargetGroupArn: !Ref ALBTargetGroupBlue
                Weight: 1

to
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: fixed-response
          FixedResponseConfig:
            StatusCode: "403"
            ContentType: "text/plain"
            MessageBody: "Access Denied"

I got the error
Transform AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen failed with: Failed to transform template. Only one Listener Action of type 'forward' is allowed for a listener. Found 0

Is there a way to do this?
I have tried to add a Rule between ALBListenerProdRule and the DefaultActions. It failed with the same error
